# Json data not displaying javascript tag<script></script>

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing form data into database like JSON object it has Google AdSense code a it was started with `<script>` closed with `</script>`. First I am doing serializing then used base64 encode data stored perfectly. While retrieving it done base64 decode first then unserialized it here JSON object came with missing `<script></script>` tag

**ex:**

```
a:1:{s:6:"top-ad";a:6:{s:5:"col-1";s:1:"7";s:10:"col-1-type";s:5:"image";s:12:"col-1-adinfo";s:43:"data/adv/landing/sarinodu.571762081eb0b.jpg";s:5:"col-2";s:2:"11";s:10:"col-2-type";s:7:"adsense";s:12:"col-2-adinfo";s:376:"
```

";}}

s:376:"here missing script code ";

Please help me what should I do yet? This is the code I wrote.

```
<?php
$select_adv = $db->query("select ad_data from adspace_obj_tbl");
$result = $select_adv->fetch();
$ad_info = base64_decode($result['ad_data']);               
$ad_data = unserialize($ad_info);               
var_dump($ad_data);             
?>
```

Comment: the script tag is there i guess, use view source in your browser to see it. btw thats not json.

Comment: Thanks :- Roland Starke  
 Array ( [top-ad] => Array ( [col-1] => 7 [col-1-type] => image [col-1-adinfo] => data/adv/landing/sarinodu.571762081eb0b.jpg [col-2] => 11 [col-2-type] => adsense [col-2-adinfo] =>  

  ) ) if i need to display echo $ad_data['top-ad']['col-1'];//prints 7 like that if prints echo $ad_data['top-ad']['col-2-adinfo'];//nothing prints

Comment: You can try to `echo htmlspecialchars($ad_data['top-ad']['col-2-adinfo']);`

Comment: There is nothing _json_  related in your question. The data you show at `ex:` is an serialized object in a php specific format. The unserialized data will be a php object. Beside that storing your data in the proprietary format of php is a bad idea, either normalize it or at least use JSON because most DBMS already support or will do in future.